# Can I brick my VBIOS by updating the drivers for my graphics card?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, bios, gpu

I currently have a problem with my nvidia graphics card. First let me give you an overview over my system. I have an early

- Razer Blade 2021 Model running an
- NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3070
- Dual Boot Kubuntu/Windows 11

Now I had the drivers installed in both systems. In linux I had to sign to sign the drivers which prompted me to roll out the keys during boot. After disabling NVIDIA optimus my machine completely went dark with the monitor not getting any output not even during the boot sequence.
Now i was able to get back to making the monitor work by blindly enabling optimus again in the bios but ever since my dedicated gpu is not working anymore. Not in Windows nor in Linux. Now the scenarios I could think of are

- The GPU was broken already and disabling optimus basically killed off the option of using the intel graphics (which is somewhat strange considering before switching off optimus in windows everything worked just fine)
- I somehow managed to damage the vbios with some linux/windows driver update combination.

Now my question is. Could I have damaged the vbios with just driver updates etc. or is it more likely that the gpu has a hardware failure? It would be great if someone could help me out. I'd be more than happy to add any more information/logs to this question if needed.

Comment: Unlikely to be bricked by drivers, but maybe there is some oddness in the boot sequence or you hit some other options while fumbling blindly around the menus. If your bios has a "restore to defaults" option then I'd try that as well as pulling out the battery for a few minutes to properly power cycle it.

Comment: I tried all of that. Also removed the cmos battery but no luck. In windows the error codes in the device manager switch between 35 and 43. In Linux the device just doesn't work

Comment: Are there any logs that could provide more insight?

Comment: What does Device Manager show in Windows?

Comment: In linux you could shuffle through the `dmesg` output, but I don't have an Optimus laptop to know what I'd be looking for.

Comment: so dmesg does show "nvidia 0000:01:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)". I also found some discussions on that error but nothing really suggested a solution. Also the possible fixes that were dsicussed relate to different kernel models. but nothing there should have effect either on windows or on the start of the laptop before an os gets loaded or am i wrong?

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-linux-driver-load-error-cant-change-power-state-from-d3cold-to-d0/202037/20 suggests that there might be a "graphics bios mode" in your system firmware options that needs to be set to "hybrid". Might be that it got changed when you disabled optimus?

Comment: hybrid should be that optimus mode where both the integrated graphics can be used as well as the dGPU as far as I know.